# Having Kafka connected with ip as well as service name - Openshift

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift

In our Openshift ecosystem, we have a kafka instance sourced from `wurstmeister/kafka`. As of now I am able to have the kafka accessible withing the `Openshift` system using the below parameters,

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka_service_name
```

And ofcourse, the params for port and zookeper is there.

I am able to access the kafka from the pods within the openshift system. But I am unable to access kafka service from the host machine. Eventhough I am able to access the kafka pod using its IP and able to telnet the pod using, `telnet Pod_IP 9092`

When I am trying to connect using the kafka producer from the host machine, I am getting the below error,

> 2017-08-07 07:45:13,925] WARN Error while fetching metadata with
>   correlation id 2 : {tls21=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

And When I try to connect from Kafka consumer from the host machine using IP, it is blank.

**Note:** As of now, its a single openshift server. And the use case is for dev testing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'host machine'? The master node of the OpenShift cluster? Your personal machine, if running this under Minishift or oc cluster up?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Its a single Openshift for now. And the use case is for dev testing.

Comment: That doesn't really help me understand what host you are talking about. If you communicate with it using a non HTTP protocol, to get access outside of the cluster for testing, you can use ``oc port-forward``. Otherwise you need to use one of the methods to configure having the service/port visible outside of the cluster.

Comment: By host, I mean the host machine on which Openshift is deployed.

Comment: In a typical OpenShift installation it would use multiple hosts. At least one master node, possible an infrastructure node, and also the actual nodes where application pods run. To say what you are would imply you must then be using Minishift, CDK, oc cluster up, or have installed OpenShift as a single node cluster. So that still doesn't clarify anything. Same still stands, you need to use port forwarding, or configure OpenShift to expose the service outside of the clusters own network. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/getting_traffic_into_cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a look at this POC for having Kafka on OpenShift ? 
https://github.com/EnMasseProject/barnabas